# How to create a custom browser in android

Tags: android

Hi i am having a activity with a button, on click of the button it has to load a custom browser in a new activity not the default browser of android. and i need a way to exclude the history of the browser such that on back press it comes back to the previous activity without navigating to previous website. I am new to android and any ways to do this

Comment: custom browser, which browser?

Comment: You can do with help of webview, look this link http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably just talking about the WebView

Link to the [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html)

Note :

> This onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent) callback method will be called anytime a
>   button is pressed while in the Activity. The condition inside uses the
>   KeyEvent to check whether the key pressed is the BACK button and
>   whether the WebView is actually capable of navigating back (if it has
>   a history). If both are true, then the goBack() method is called,
>   which will navigate back one step in the WebView history.Returning
>   true indicates that the event has been handled. If this condition is
>   not met, then the event is sent back to the system.

Comment: thanks for the reply, Reno could you help me with the code if possible on the same as i have no clue to do this. thanks agian

Comment: I can, you will have to start first by following the tutorial. If you get stuck anywhere, sure you can ask me anything.

Comment: may i have your email id or any other contact info ?

Comment: Sorry asking for email is frowned upon on this website, why don't you [drop by chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android) and give me a holler.

Comment: I've given write access to you

Answer (score 1):

You can start by putting a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) in an activity.

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you help me doing this i have no idea about it

Comment: The tutorial that Reno linked is probably a good start: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a view which can browse the web in your app then make use of the WebView view.

Else if you want to create your own custom browser, then you have to make use Web engine WebKit present in the library layer of the android.